# Connect to Oracle Database 11g using PHP

Tags: php, oracle11g, xampp

How to connect to Oracle Database 11G using PHP?

I want to get an explanation about database cache because I want to test the response time of web application that builds database cache.

Answer (score 0):

You connect to Oracle 11g as any other Oracle DB using [oci_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php) function.

```
$conn = oci_connect('hr', 'welcome', 'localhost/XE');
```

Php has no built in caching, but try to read about [memcache](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) or [apc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php)